# Move File After Downloading

Tags: swift, string, url, nsfilemanager

Im using parse to download some files to the device and all is good but i want to then move the file from the default cache directory which is where parse stores them (/Library/Caches/PFFileCache/) to somewhere more stable say the users documents directory.

The localised error i am getting is:

```
Error: “7b54d8a0f1a64b710058d4408ca4d696_The%20Name%20of%20the%20Wind%2029-92.mp3” couldn’t be moved to “Documents” because either the former doesn't exist, or the folder containing the latter doesn't exist.
```

But I'm sure both exist.  It may be something to do with the name as when i ge the name from the PFFile it doesn't have the encoded %20 in the file name.

This is my code block:

```
    let cachedPFFile = object.object(forKey: "partAudio") as! PFFile
        print(cachedPFFile)
    let getCachedFilePath = cachedPFFile.getPathInBackground()
        getCachedFilePath.waitUntilFinished()
    let cachedFilePath = getCachedFilePath.result as! String
        print(cachedFilePath)

    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = String(describing: paths[0])

    let saveDirectory = documentsDirectory.appending(cachedPFFile.name)

        print(documentsDirectory)
        print(saveDirectory)

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: saveDirectory) == false {

        do {
            try fileManager.moveItem(atPath: cachedFilePath, toPath: saveDirectory)
            print("Move successful")
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
```

This is the entire log:

```
<PFFile: 0x608000458f00>
2017-02-20 18:42:35.430 ParseStarterProject-Swift[2260:55934] Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
/Users/Genie/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A2FB00CE-B018-4FDF-9635-35FD6678DF8D/data/Containers/Data/Application/BA7C112C-BECB-4734-8C67-A9CB84F0E1F3/Library/Caches/Parse/PFFileCache/7b54d8a0f1a64b710058d4408ca4d696_The%20Name%20of%20the%20Wind%2029-92.mp3
file:///Users/Genie/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A2FB00CE-B018-4FDF-9635-35FD6678DF8D/data/Containers/Data/Application/BA7C112C-BECB-4734-8C67-A9CB84F0E1F3/Documents/
file:///Users/Genie/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A2FB00CE-B018-4FDF-9635-35FD6678DF8D/data/Containers/Data/Application/BA7C112C-BECB-4734-8C67-A9CB84F0E1F3/Documents/7b54d8a0f1a64b710058d4408ca4d696_The Name of the Wind 29-92.mp3
Error: “7b54d8a0f1a64b710058d4408ca4d696_The%20Name%20of%20the%20Wind%2029-92.mp3” couldn’t be moved to “Documents” because either the former doesn't exist, or the folder containing the latter doesn't exist.
```

I am confused by this because both the file and the new directory exist??

though I'm not sure about the "file:///Users" as this doesn't work in finder, have to use the true path "/Users"  how can i remove "file://" from the start of the string??

Also I've been searching SO without luck on how to add the %20 in the spaces of the file name none of the obvious options seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have threading issues. Your entire idea of "waitUntilFinished" is wrong. You cannot block the main thread — and you are getting a warning telling you so. Listen to that warning!

Do not call `getFilePathInBackground`, and do not wait for the download to finish. Instead, call `getFileInBackgroundWithBlock:`, and *inside the block* proceed with the rest of your code, i.e. move the file.

Comment: i tried this originally but it was not returning a path so went with the waituntilfinished().  You are right though, ill look at it some more.  the issue with my constructed path to documents folder was the file:// if i remove this it moves the file fine

Comment: "but it was not returning a path" It hands the path _into the block_.

Comment: i just tried it again and it does hand it to the block.  for some reason i had it in my head that it didn't??

Comment: Right. So now move _all_ the rest of the code into the block and all will be well, because you won't be holding up the main thread any more. And never do that again! :)